# load sp.js from a js file

Tags: sharepoint-server, language

I've developped a js file (located in site library/js) and inside, i'd like to get the selected language of the site. (sharepoint 2010)
So when i do this, i've got an exception in the success method where telling me
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_language'

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', ready);

function ready() {
    // some code here
    clientContext= SP.ClientContext.get_current();//new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    web = clientContext.get_web(); 

    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onRequestSucceeded),  Function.createDelegate(this, onRequestFailed));

}
function onRequestSucceeded(web, args) {
    alert("success");
    //i get an exception SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_language' 
    var lcid=web.get_language() ;
    alert('LCID:'+lcid);

}
     function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

No one function works on my web like get_url or something else

Comment: how can i see this?

Comment: i do this in a content editor webpart where i link to my js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your success callback function.

Replace the line:

```
function onRequestSucceeded(web, args) {
```

to

```
function onRequestSucceeded(sender, args) {
```

Comment: Good spot, I did not even see that.

Comment: very weel, i've the noze on and looking for a solution for about 2 hours. thanks

Comment: do you know why the language stay always on 1033? i select other lang from my user menu without change

Comment: In order to test/debug JS code snippets you could use browser capabilities, see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx